# ansible how to use custom script to become root

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I have read that "--become-user=root" using ansible adhoc command and playbook has also  similar type task is being is used.

My problem is , in our provisioned vms , we don't have privilege to become root using sudo command

we have custom script to become root , then only we can do what a root can do

example : i have to issue below command to become root and perform root operations . so how can we achieve this from ansible

```
[dummyuser@slcpqc somedir]$ /usr/local/packages/somer/install/run_as_root bash
bash-4.2#
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be of use https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/become/su.html

Your case would be something like:

```
- hosts: bamboo
  become: yes
  become_method: su
  become_exe: "/usr/local/packages/somer/install/run_as_root"
```

Answer (score 0):

We'd really need to understand more about how the script accepts and uses argument and redirections, but if we make a few reasonable assumptions, you should be able to put all the commands you want into a script and execute it with `run_as_root`.

```
- name: Create a script to run the commands you want
  template: src=your.sh dest=/tmp/my.sh

- name: run the script
  command: /usr/local/packages/somer/install/run_as_root bash /tmp/my.sh
```

This lets you slot in any last-minute values relevant to the local system.